# Elasticsearch delete_by_query wrong usage

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-py

I am using 2 similar ES methods to load and delete documents:

```
result = es.search(index='users_favourite_documents',
                   doc_type='favourite_document',
                   body={"query": {"match": {'user': user}}})
```

And:

```
result = es.delete_by_query(index='users_favourite_documents',
                            doc_type='favourite_document',
                            body={"query": {"match": {'user': user}}})
```

First one works ok and returns expected records.
Second one throws Exception:

> "TransportError(404,'{
>   \"found\":false,
>   \"_index\":\"users_favourite_documents\",
>   \"_type\":\"favourite_document\",
>   \"_id\":\"_query\",
>   \"_version\":1,
>   \"_shards\":{\"total\":2,\"successful\":2,
>   \"failed\":0}}')"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What version of ES are you using?

Comment: Version of ES == 2.3

Comment: Unfortunately it's not mine ES server. I managed to solve problem by using search as first step to get _id  and normal delete() (which uses previously acquired _id) as the second step.

Comment: Ok, gotcha. If you manage to get a hand on the server, the answer will still be valid, though.

Answer (score 5):

I'v used version 6.2.0 of the Elastic Stack and the use of the API works for deleting like this:

```
es.delete_by_query(index="index_name", doc_type='doc_type', body={"query":{"match": {"message": "message_value"}}})
```

if your value is INT remove the "" in message_value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running recent versions of ES (5/6/7/8), the [_delete_by_query endpoint is supported natively](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-delete-by-query.html). No need to install anything.

If you're running ES 2.x, you need to make sure that you have installed the [delete-by-query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html) first:

In your ES_HOME folder, run this:

```
bin/plugin install delete-by-query
```

Then restart ES and your `es.delete_by_query(...)` call will work.

If you're running ES 1.x, then delete-by-query is part of the core and that should work out of the box.