# Unable to delete documents from ElasticSearch Index using cURL commands

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I have setup an ElasticSearch Index in Windows 7 64 Bit OS. Here are is my sample document :

```
{
      "_index" : "mydocdeleteindex",
      "_type" : "prod",
      "_id" : "AVceQ_DnIBf8JBhpZhxj",
      "_score" : 1.0,
      "_timestamp" : 1473681551591,
      "_source" : {
        "Name" : "My Sample DashBoards",
        "ID" : "forcheckdocdel",
        "Time" : "2016-09-02 07:14:23"
      }
    },
```

....

I would like to delete all the documents with "Name":"My Sample DashBoards"
I executed the below cURL commands and none of it worked!

```
curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/mydocdeleteindex/prod/_query -d '{"query":{"_source":{"Name":"My Sample DashBoards"}}}'

curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/mydocdeleteindex/prod/_query -d '{"query":{"term":{"Name":"My Sample DashBoards"}}}'

curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/mydocdeleteindex/prod/_query?q=Name:My Sample DashBoards

curl -XDELETE localhost:9200/mydocdeleteindex/prod/_query?q="Name":"My Sample
DashBoards"
```

I get the below errors (in order):

```
1. {"found":false,"_index":"mydocdeleteindex","_type":"prod","_id":"_query","
_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}


2. {"found":false,"_index":"mydocdeleteindex","_type":"prod","_id":"_query","
_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}


3. {"found":false,"_index":"mydocdeleteindex","_type":"prod","_id":"_query","
_version":1,"_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}curl:(6) Could not resolve host: Sample curl: (6) Could not resolve host: DashBoards

4. curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

No change happens and I see all the data perfectly available! :(

Comment: Which version of Elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: This answer will probably help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39328892/elasticsearch-delete-by-query-wrong-usage/39329398#39329398 (hint: you need to install the delete-by-query plugin)

Comment: @Val I am using ES 2.3.5

Comment: Ok, then see my linked answer above and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install delete_by_query plugin and try the same commands